# Delete old simulators from Xcode

Tags: xcode

I installed Xcode 4.3, and also 4.3 and 5.0 simulators, so I ended up with 3 pair of simulators.

How can I delete the old simulators?

Answer (score 6):

You can delete them in the following directory, but I'm not completely sure if deleting them here will remove them from the list of simulators in Xcode.

However you should probably keep them all installed, the more testing you can do on different iOS versions, the better!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove them from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes